# ReactJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined but it is

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map function that is supposed to take the data from an list I've created and show it to the user but it give me a typerror whenever I try to do that, here's my map function:

```
{product.map((item, idx)=>
            <div key={idx}>
                    <h3 className='productName'>{item[idx].name}</h3>
                    <div className='productImageContainer'>
                        <img src={item[idx].image}></img>
                    </div>
                    <span className='productPrice'><strong>${item[idx].Price}.00</strong></span>
                    <br></br>
                    <Button className='removeProductButton' variant='danger'><MdCancel></MdCancel> Remove</Button>

            </div>)}
```

And here's the piece of code where I attach the items to the array:

```
    const [product, getProduct]= useState([])
const getProducts=()=>
{
    let X = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))
    getProduct([...product, X])
}
```

I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined", I've tried manually console logging each element of the list and it is definitely not undefined, why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `name` property directly on `item` like so:

```
<h3 className='productName'>{item.name}</h3>
```

`item` is the current element that is being processed in your list.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but whenever I do it it doesn't really show anyhing unless I index it

Comment: The answer is correct though. Check your `products`

Comment: Most likely your `products` list isn't what you think it is. Doing `item[idx].name` isn't going to work.

Comment: I'll look into it

Comment: Hmm, yeah, apparently the product list is, for some obscure to me at least, reason empty even after I append those value to it, hmm. Thank you for the cooperation though

Comment: Why are you mapping through a single product btw? Isn't it ``products.map(...)``? And you should indeed use ``item.name``. 

Maybe use Redux instead of the regular localStorage next? ;)

Comment: Well I've declared the list as  product because I've looked at them as individual products being looped over one after another

Comment: Speaking of using Redux, how would such a thing be done with it?

Answer (score 1):

When you are mapping through an array you are already going through each element, that is what the 'item' field in your code is. It is the each individual item from the array that you're mapping.

Now coming to why it throws up the error:
When you are mapping through an array and you are inside a particular item, and you try to do item[idX].name, it is trying to find the object with the key of value idX in your case which is undefined and since it is undefined it throws up the error that it cannot read the property 'name' (which you're trying to access) of undefined.

Solution:

- simply do {item.name} to access name of the item object (the object of the particular iteration you're on).
- you can destructure the things that you want from item as well to make your code look clear. ref: https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/

Hope this clears your doubt :)